# How to use Markdown & MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I want my users to be able to comment using Markdown and avoiding XSS.

What is the correct sequence of actions to do ?

This is my understanding of how it works:

```
user input via HTML form using Markdown syntax
$Input = markdown(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userInput']));
insert $input into database
```

And then, Do I need also to use htmlspecialchars ?

Comment: What does `markdown` do? And why do you run it before storing the data?

Comment: You're using `mysql_query`, aren't you?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: dont convert the input to markdown. convert the output to markdown instead. Otherwise there will be no way to edit the markdown because it's html then in the database.

Comment: It might not be a good idea to run the markdown parser each time the output is rendered - parsing the comment is quite expensive and the usual blog comment (as an example) is far more often read than written.

Answer (score 0):

**mysql_real_escape_string** is used to avoid SQL INJECTION. Because it escapes SQL.

XSS can be avoided using strip_tags(), preg_match() and htmlspecialchars() together

XSS is based on html tags that contains exploits. For example scripts in java script, or redirections, or opening files in  tags.

strip_tags() removes html tags. Also there is one more interesting function called

htmlspecialchars() for preventing XSS.

The most imporant things to prevent sql injection attack

1. Data Validation using preg_match
2. Data Sanitization using strip_tags
3. Output Escaping using htmlspecialchars

so first you should validate data, then sanitize it and finally escape it using htmlspecialchars.

Comment: This guy who downvoted my post should rewrite his scripts againts security and know what is difference between XSS and SQL injection.

Comment: I down-voted it because at the time it was a very brief answer that didn't provide a solution. You've expanded it since then. I'm quite vigilant about making sure people understand SQL injection issues, even to the point of being irritating.

Answer (score 0):

Escaping should be the last thing you do before inserting data into the database. Running `markdown`, or any other function on it at that point, is too late.

Secondly, HTML escaping and Markdown conversion is a *display* concern, and should not affect what's written to the database. Perform these functions when rendering an HTML page, and not before. The database should contain the raw markdown, not the HTML version.